# Matlab to Python Translation - Dividing Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy

Ok I have the following codes and I can't seem to work out why they don't do the same thing, I'm trying to replicate the Matlab:

**Matlab**

```
buflen = 1024
overlap = 512

blend = ones(buflen,1);
blend(1:overlap+1) = 0:1/overlap:1;
blend(buflen-overlap:buflen) = 1:-1/overlap:0
```

**Python**

```
buflen = 1024
overlap = 512

blend = np.ones(buflen)
blend[0:overlap+1] = np.arange(0,2)/np.arange(overlap:1)
blend[buflen-overlap-1:buflen] = np.arange(1,-1)/np.arange(overlap,0)
```

I'm currently stuck at the second line in the main code, In matlab "0:1/overlap:1" produces a 513x1 array from 0 to 1 in steps of 0.001953125.

In Python, "np.arange(0,2)/np.arange(overlap:1)" it just doesn't doesn't work.
I can't work out what is going on in Matlab.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you use `np.arange(start,end,STEP)?`

Comment: the cleanest  would probably be `np.linspace(0, 1, overlap+1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure but is it possible that you are simply misreading the Matlab syntax. Using parenthesis may help clarify a bit:

1. `0:(1/overlap):1` is not same as
2. `(0:1)/(overlap:1)`.

The first one means go from `0` to `1` in steps of `(1/overlap)` whereas second one is trying to divide two arrays.

If you want Python to behave like the first code snippet you should use

```
np.arange(0, 1 + (1/overlap), 1/overlap)
```

Or even better as @PaulPanzer suggested

```
np.linspace(0, 1, 1+overlap)
```

Comment: Perfect, the issue as you said was how I was reading the matlab code!
Thanks very much for suggesting np.linspace too.